# Start a java application with terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I'm trying to create a java application which starts a new terminal without using *java -jar*. I tried using several methods, but none of them have worked.

I need this to work on osx, I was able to make it on windwos

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What did you do on Windows?  By the way, something was probably doing `java -jar` under the hood on Windows.

Comment: I tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal java -jar myjar.jar gui" and on start I'm checking if gui is in the start arguments

Comment: On windows i used the method explaimed above but instead of "open -a Terminal" I used "start -c"

Comment: why `without using java -jar` ?

Comment: @biology.info I mean without writing java -jar in the terminal

Comment: ok i see, please add osx tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your shell as a program

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 String[] args = { "/bin/sh", "-c", " java -jar myjar.jar" };
 final Process process = runtime.exec(args);
```

To respond to your specific request, this is my answer

**1/ Create a shell script**

For example call it loadJava.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar
```

**2/ Call the shell script** with this java code that open a terminal and run the shell script

Correct code for OSX is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal /path/to/the/script");
```

Comment: /bin/sh/ is not a directory on osx

Comment: please remove end slash

Comment: But it does not create a new terminal window where i can see the output

Comment: But this still does not start my application in a new window. I want that if you double click the application it starts in a terminal